# Chart.js with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I want to implement charts in my project, and I decided to use react-chart.js

I'm at the very beginning trying to add an example in my components, so I added this code :

```
var MyChart = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    console.log(chartData)
    return <LineChart data={chartData} options={null} width="600" height="250"/>
  }
});

module.exports = MyChart;
```

chartData is an object

I have an err:

> core.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)[chartType] is not
>   a function

I also tried other charts, but none of them did work, so I probably do something wrong, but I can't find what

Comment: r u using ReCharts ?? from where u r importing LineChart ?

Comment: Refer to this.  It may help.  https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs/issues/112

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`React Chartjs` has a dependency on `Chart.js` too. 
Install it like

```
npm install --save chart.js@^1.1.1 react react-dom
```

Also since `Line` is a `named export` you need to import it as

```
import {Line as LineChart} from 'react-chartjs';
```

Also make sure your chartData is an object like

```
{
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fill: false,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            spanGaps: false,
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Do you know if i can reuse this component? my app doesn't work when I add <MyChart/> to a container

Comment: You should be a able to reuse this component as long as you provide the correct data and options

Comment: I have null in options, and I can't reuse it in other components, or even place the element inside a div. What should I add to fix that?

Comment: I am not sure Elena, I did not face such issues with react-chartjs. For me its works fine